# how to place a chart with xlwings at a particular worksheet range address from python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am unable to position a chart at a given location  on the activesheet in excel from python code shown below. I can produce the chart but cannot control the placement location on the worksheet. I am an absolute beginner and may not have followed all the required conventions in the forum. Apologies. Vas

```
   from __future__ import division
   get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')


   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from matplotlib import rc
   from sympy import *
   from IPython.display import display as dsp
   from IPython.display import  Math, Latex
   import xlwings as xw

   plt.plot(psr,dphs)
   plot = xw.Plot(fig)
   #xlwings.shapes.shape.top = Range('A23') DID NOT WORK
   plot.show('Plot1')
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently, there's only a left and top position implemented in points:

```
plot.show('Plot1', left=10, top=30)
```

For xlwings >= v0.6.0, you can do:

```
plot.show('Plot1', left=Range('A1').left, top=Range('A1').top)
```

For xlwings <0.6.0, just follow the workarounds as described [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/missing_features.html):

The following shows the workaround applied to the picture object returned by the  `show` method as alternative to setting it within the show method directly (Windows version):

```
pic = plot.show('Plot1')
pic.top = Range('A1').xl_range.Top
pic.left = Range('A1').xl_range.Left
```

Comment: Thank You. Much appreciated.

Comment: Stackoverflow's way of saying thank you is by accepting the answer and possibly upvoting it ;-)

Comment: I've updated my answer as this is now available with xlwings v0.6.0